# Sound of hard drive coming from inside wall?

Tags: electrical, noise

Last night I heard a sound that sounds *exactly* like an in-use hard-drive coming from our living room wall.  It sounded exactly like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J09pWNQPK7U&t=12s

with the same short bursts of extremely fast low-tone clicks at random intervals, followed by varying lengths of silence.

Nearby the apparent source of the sound we have:

- A normal electrical outlet, a few feet below the source
- The electrical panel for the house *(we have no basement, so it's in our living room)* a few feet to the left
- A mini-split ~ 10 feet to the right, which was set to 'heating'

I'm worried it may have been an electrical problem, but I've never heard of arcing sounding like a hard-drive before.  The sound went away in the early hours of the morning.

What could have caused this sort of noise?

Comment: Guessing you have mice.

Comment: @crip659: Are mice able to 'click' that fast?

Comment: When they are chewing and scratching.  Could also be bugs(insects, not NSA)

Comment: Stand in the living room and ask them to upgrade their bug to a solid state drive. ;^)

Comment: I agree that it is mice. If you have not had chronic rodent problems, and you take fast action, you can probably rid yourself of the pests fairly easily....don't wait until they dig in!

Comment: @izzy  if they are making enough noise to bug a person, they already dug in.  Time to punch holes in walls and drop poison in.

Comment: Possibly I got off easy, but I promptly put out poison in corners and under things, and my problem went away.

Comment: @izzy find if you can hear them, you have problem.  They usually do not want you to know they are around, except for their gifts.